# External hard drive failure - data recovery - highly possible hardware error

Tags: data-recovery

I am using Ubuntu 17.04.

My external hard drive is `WD my Passport Ultra 2.0TB USB 3.0`.

Earlier this day I was copying about 40 large files - each around 5GB - when my system experienced an error.

The OS stopped responding for about 5 minutes and then resumed normal work, with one exception, the process of copying the data was interrupted, and that has caused me to be unable to read or write to this disk. Upon each attempt, I get an `I/O error` message.

I believe this OS "error" was caused by excessive CPU usage - I was running two virtual machines in VMware Workstation 12 at the time.

I rebooted my computer, but I was unable to mount this disk. In addition, the hard disk began to beep (single beep per 2 or 3 minutes).

I booted into system recovery mode. After I plugged the device, this pops up:

[image]

I am able to mount the external hard drive but all my folders are empty. What do I do next?

**EDIT:**

`lsusb` output:

```
patryk@ubuntu-pc:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 1058:0827 Western Digital Technologies, Inc.
```

This hard drive is spinning because i can hear it (from close distance)
Also it is beeping agine. Single beep per 2 or 3 minutes.

Comment: All signs show a hardware error, please update the highly misleading title.

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto  done. I am new to the linux world. I believed it wasn't hardware, because of the circumstances, Now i am not quite sure anymore.

Comment: Good. Having an accurate title usually attracts better answers and helps getting the attention of people expert on the topic. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It indicates a hardware error, but...

**Step #1:**

Lets first check your file system for errors.

If sdb has a EXT4 partition at sdb1, then...

In `terminal`...

- type `sudo fsck -f /dev/sdb1` # change sdb1 if need be
- repeat the fsck command if there were errors

If your external drive has a NTFS partition, then...

- boot into Windows
- open an administrative command prompt window
- type `chkdsk /f d:` (change drive letter d if need be)

**Step #2:**

In Ubuntu, open the `Disks` application. Select the correct drive in the left pane. Go to the "hamburger" icon and select `SMART Data & Self Tests`. Review the data, and run the tests.

**Update:**

You have either a bad USB cable, or a USB->SATA bridge card in the enclosure, or a bad hard drive. I'd guess the hard drive.

Comment: Why do you think its hardware error?

Comment: @cukier9a7b5 because it indicates a hardware error right in your images. My answer, step #1 assumes it's not a hardware problem, but step #2 assumes that it might be a hardware error. Have you done those steps? Report back.

Comment: This hard drive had single NTFS partition. I boot into Windows to perform 'chkdsk /f X:' but system could not detect this drive. I booted into ubuntu and disk was not recognized. Only  `lsusb` can detect this drive. Therefor is no `/dev/sdb` or `/dev/sdb1` storage device

Comment: @cukier9a7b5 did you give it a proper drive letter in the chkdsk command, or did you use X? Did the `Disks` app not find the drive either? If not, try `gparted` repair.

Comment: Yes, I used the correct drive letter in the `chkdsk` command. I  replaced correct letter with "X" to avoid confusion. The correct letter is "E". Yes `Disks` app did not find the drive. `gparted` did not find it either. I don't know what is going on, but I can't detect this drive as storage device. Only `lsusb` can see it.

Comment: I have found this `ddrescue` [method](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20050720092514388). *(I did not compile ddrescue, i downloaded it from repository)* I would like to try it, but since OS can't detect this drive anymore, I am unable to execute `ddrescue -v /dev/sdb MyVolImage.dmg MyVolRescue.log` because there is no `sdb` storage. I believe that `sdb` is a valid designation - `sda` is the only other storage device.

Comment: For the sake of the data, do not run `chkdsk` on a heavily damaged NTFS drive!

Comment: @cukier9a7b5 the next step would be to try a new USB cable. The next step would be to remove the drive from the enclosure and try to access it from another computer with a SATA port. The problem is either the USB->SATA bridge in the enclosure, or the hard drive is defective.

Comment: @heynnema I've already tried it. I have bought two of these external hard drives. And I have check the cable under working disk. The cable works fine, also USB port works fine too. I have gave up, at this point, and I just send my disk to the data recovery specialist. Hopefully He will be able to recover my "treasure".

Comment: @heynnema Thank you for all your help! Btw. You have said, that you suspect defective hard drive. Do you think it would be possible to recover the data from this hardware failure? I am not very experienced in tech-stuff...

Comment: @cukier9a7b5 You're very welcome. Data recovery can be very expensive. I'd first try removing the drive from the enclosure and connecting it elsewhere.

Comment: As mentioned, do not try fsck the disk that have hardware errors, as that can ruin data on it.
Try to move the data away.
I have found PhotoRec/TestDisk to be usefull, IF the OS can find the disk.  It works with all three major OS:es.  And yes, you can download the archive, extract and run from a Live Ubuntu, if the OS is on the faulty disk. Only have another storage available (over net or on the machine, like USB disk).
If the disk doesn't spin up, you MIGHT be able to unlock it by opening it.  But then the disk should be used any more (as it shouldn't anyway). The error say it is a HW err